# Why is a web page rendering improperly only on my machine, in all browsers?

Tags: browser, html, malware, rendering

I have recently created a website using GitHub and R/RStudio. In the last few days I have encountered the following problem: the 'resume' part of my website renders improperly on my computer, irrespective of browser (Mozilla,, Chrome, Edge). It renders correctly on my phone, my wife and friends' computers, my second lap top. I have added a screen shot of how it renders on my computer (again, in all browsers). Here is a [link to the page in question](https://www.andrewmcameron.com/resume_beta.html). When I knit/render the RMarkdown file in RStudio that the html page is generated from, the html file renders correctly when I open it with a browser. It only renders improperly when I access it from the hosted site at the link above. [Screen shot of rendering on my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02tRf.png)

After restarting my computer last week (a Dell laptop), the machine initiated an update of my drivers. I had restarted the computer because of sudden odd behavior (inability to type, clicking browser tabs generated a blue outline around the tab but I could not actually close or switch between tabs). I was concerned about malware, and wondered it the driver update was legitimate. However, the only odd behavior I have noticed since this driver update is what I have described with the single resume page on my website (everything else renders perfectly fine).

I have also done malware scans using AVG and Windows Defender, and those returned no issues. Whether that is dispositive of anything, I don't know.
Additionally, I cleared the cache on all browsers, as well as a hard refresh on the page in question. I also use an external monitor. I unplugged the monitor, restarted the computer, and tried to load the page again, but it still continues to render in this wonky way.

Thanks for any thoughts/help.

Comment: [Showing results for https://www.andrewmcameron.com/resume_beta.html - Nu Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.andrewmcameron.com%2Fresume_beta.html) 3 errors and 1 warning. Fix those and retest.

Comment: Thank you @DavidPostill . I will work on fixing those. I am still curious to understand why it is seemingly only a problem that manifests on my computer, and other machines appear able to deal with the errors. Have you got any thoughts on that?

Comment: There is a city called `Newport News`. Is their local newspaper called Newport News News?

Comment: In the sourcecode on your computer, do the links to the css and js files work?

Comment: The screenshot makes it look like there is no content after a certain point. Do "view page source" on your device and a working one, then diff them to make sure your device actually got the same content from the site. See if the browser dev tools console shows errors/warnings on your PC that aren't on others? The main things that can mess with site contents on only your device are browser extensions, malware (often trying to insert ads), and antivirus, so try to rule those out.